# Loading Status on alertdialog

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app which shows details when clicked on a list view.
The details are shown on a alertDialog.Builder

These details are fetched from a remote service so there is time delay and I want to 
show a progress bar or a loading symbol until i get the data,

I use a sync call to get my data by using `http.execute(strUrl).get()`

please help me with this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you post your code it will be easier for the community to give you helpful answers

Comment: @user2880356 Have you used AsyncTask ?

Comment: I am calling the service using Async task, 
this is my Code:  

protected void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute();
   if (_showProgressDlg) {
        this._progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
      this.context,
      null,
      "Loading...",
      true,
      false,
      null
      );
   }

  }

This piece of code is executing, but I am stil not getting the loading symbol before the dialog appears.